# Solving $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n}=4^n$ using generating functions

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

So I have to show this identity. $$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n}=4^n$$
I tried two techniques to do it. First one would be seeing that it's convolution of two sequences: $\langle 2^n \rangle _{n=0}^\infty$ and $\langle \binom{2n}{n} \rangle _{n=0}^\infty$
That gives me:
$$\lbrack \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n x^n \rbrack \times \lbrack \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^n \rbrack =$$
$$\frac{1}{1-2x} \  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} =$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n-k}$$
So now we need to show that
$$\lbrack x^n \rbrack \frac{1}{1-2x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \frac{1}{1-4x}$$ But i'm unable to do it.

Second method would be snake oil method:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n} =$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty x^n \binom{2n-k}{n} = \text{where l := n - k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k x^k \sum_{l=0}^\infty x^l \binom{2l + k}{l+k} $$
But i'm stuck here too.
I mean i know that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
And if i multiply it by $x^k$ i get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n+2k}{n+k} x^{n+k} = \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
And it's almost what i need to calculate... but yeah, almost.

I will really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a variation based upon the *coefficient of* method. We use the symbol $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^p$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  [z^p](1+z)^q=\binom{q}{p}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-k}{n}2^k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[z^n](1+z)^{2n-k}2^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^n](1+z)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^n](1+z)^{2n}\frac{1-\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{2}{1+z}}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{(1+z)^{2n+1}-2^{n+1}(1+z)^n}{z-1}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{z}\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{-j}\left((1+z)^{2n+1}-2^{n+1}(1+z)^n\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n[z^{n+1+j}](1+z)^{2n+1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n+1+j}\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{j}\tag{8}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}2^{2n+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4^n}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we do some rearrangements and use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (4) and (5) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (6) we use the rule $[z^{p+q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^{-q}A(z)$ and restrict the upper limit of the sum with $n$ since the exponent $n+1+j\leq2n+1$. The second binomial $(1+z)^n$ does not contribute to $[z^{n+1+j}]$ and can be skipped.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{n-j}$.
- In (8) we replace $j$ with $n-j$ and apply the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{q-p}$.

*Hint:* The Cauchy product in your approach is slightly different, since
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n\color{blue}{-2k}}{n-k}\right)x^n
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I really like your method of solving various generating functions.

Comment: @Spinach: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful! :-)

Comment: (+1) This is a nice approach. I just worked on [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507702/proving-4n-sum-k-0n2k-binom2n-kn). I see that this is similar to [another answer of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782812). It would be nice to link them with a link in the answer or a comment reference.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks a lot, robjohn. Good idea, I've added the links. Btw: I can't upvote your answer, since I've did it already today. :-)

Comment: Is (1) valid, considering $\binom{2n-k}{n} \neq 0$ if $k > 2n$?

Comment: @Fikilis: Many thanks for pointing out the mistake. Answer corrected.