# Showing $ \frac{2^j(2k-j)!}{(k-j)!}=\sum_{l=j}^k\frac{2^ll(2k-l-1)!}{(k-l)!} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, arithmetic, factorial

For any given $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$, with $j\leq k$, how is it possible to prove the following equivalence?
$$
\frac{2^j(2k-j)!}{(k-j)!}=\sum_{l=j}^k\frac{2^ll(2k-l-1)!}{(k-l)!}
$$
My attempt is:
$$
\frac{2^j(2k-j)!}{(k-j)!}=\sum_{l=j}^k\frac{2^ll(2k-l-1)!}{(k-l)!}\\
2^j\binom{2k-j}{k-j}k!=\sum_{l=j}^k\binom{2k-l-1}{k-l}l2^l(k-1)!\\\binom{2k-j}{k-j}k=\sum_{l=j}^kl2^{l-j} \binom{2k-l-1}{k-l}
$$
and then I don't know how to continue. Maybe there is some binomial formula for this sum, but I don't know.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508257) is very close.

Comment: Yes, I see thank you! But I can’t apply it to my situation.

Comment: You can !! Just use ${n}\choose{r}$ = ${n}\choose{n-r}$ to reach the linked question

Comment: But that sum start at k=1 and mine at l=j

Comment: And $\displaystyle\sum_{l = 1}^k = \sum_{l = 1}^{j-1} + \sum_{l = j}^k$; the $\displaystyle \sum_{l = 1}^{j-1}$ is the linked question with a different $k$. To relate the two sums will probably take some work, but seems doable.

Comment: @JakobStreipel You mean the sum from 1 to k is related to the linked question right? Because for the sum ending at j-1 how could apply the linked question?

Comment: Is there a way to prove it by induction? Even if I have two parameters j and k.

Comment: @Brino this is direct by induction on $j$. Base case $j=k$, for the induction step, go from $j$ to $j-1$. I can post a full answer later if you haven't figured it out

Comment: Yes, please. It would be very helpful

Comment: @Brino in fact the linked question is a special case of this one, I believe there may be a generating functions approach too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the last term of your sum as
$$
\sum\limits_{\ell  = j}^{k - 1} {\frac{{2^\ell  \ell (2k - \ell  - 1)!}}{{(k - \ell )!}}}  + \frac{{2^k k(2k - k - 1)!}}{{(k - k)!}} = \sum\limits_{\ell  = j}^{k - 1} {\frac{{2^\ell  \ell (2k - \ell  - 1)!}}{{(k - \ell )!}}}  + 2^k k!,
$$
and note the [telescoping property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$$
\frac{{2^\ell  \ell (2k - \ell  - 1)!}}{{(k - \ell )!}} = \frac{{2^\ell  (2k - \ell )!}}{{(k - \ell )!}} - \frac{{2^{\ell  + 1} (2k - (\ell  + 1))!}}{{(k - (\ell  + 1))!}},
$$ for $j\le \ell \le k-1$.

Comment: Ah, I was so into finding an answer by induction that I forgot to notice my induction step could be used to telescope the sum directly! (+1)

Comment: @Gary: Very nice observation and elegant approach. (+1) In fact the generating function approach is done until the telescoping in the line after (9) becomes obvious. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a generating function approach that generalises @MarkoRiedel's answer to *[this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508257)*. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n = \binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We show the following identity is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{l=j}^k\binom{2k-l-1}{k-l}l\,2^{l-j}=k\binom{2k-j}{k-j}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{l=j}^k}&\color{blue}{\binom{2k-l-1}{k-l}l\,2^{l-j}}\\
> &=\sum_{l=j}^k[z^{k-l}](1+z)^{2k-l-1}l\,2^{l-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^k](1+z)^{2k-1}\sum_{l=j}^\infty\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^ll\,2^{l-j}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^k](1+z)^{2k-1}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{l+j}(l+j)2^l\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{k-j}](1+z)^{2k-j-1}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^l(l+j)\\
> &=[z^{k-j}](1+z)^{2k-j-1}\left(\frac{2z(1+z)}{(1-z)^2}+j\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=2[z^{k-j}](1+z)^{2k-j}\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}+j[z^{k-j}](1+z)^{2k-j}\frac{1}{1-z}\\
> &=2\sum_{m=0}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j}{m}(k-j-m)+j\sum_{m=0}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j}{m}\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j}{2k-j-m}(2k-j-m)-\sum_{m=1}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j}{m}m\tag{8}\\
> &=(2k-j)\sum_{m=0}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j-1}{2k-j-m-1}-(2k-j)\sum_{m=1}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j-1}{m-1}\tag{9}\\
> &=(2k-j)\sum_{m=0}^{k-j}\binom{2k-j-1}{m}-(2k-j)\sum_{m=0}^{k-j-1}\binom{2k-j-1}{m}\\
> &=(2k-j)\binom{2k-j-1}{k-j}=(2k-j)\binom{2k-j-1}{k-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=k\binom{2k-j}{k}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (4) we apply $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and some rearrangements. We also set the upper limit to $\infty$ without changing anything thanks to $[z^k]$.
- in (5) we shift the index to start with $j=0$.
- In (6) we recall the *[binomial series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}qz^q\qquad\qquad\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}z^q
  \end{align*}
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{k-j}$ recalling the Cauchy product of series.
- In (8) we apply $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ and rearrange the sums.
- In (9) we apply $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using induction:

Let the RHS be $f(j)$, with $0\le j\le k$. We prove by induction that:
$$P(j): f(j) = \color{red}{\frac{2^j(2k-j)!}{(k-j)!}}$$is true for $j \le k$.

For the base case $j=k$, note that the sum has only one summand, i.e,
$$f(\color{blue}{k}) = \frac{2^{\color{blue}{k}}\color{blue}{k} (2k-\color{blue}{k}-1)!}{(k-\color{blue}{k})!} = \color{red}{\frac{2^k(2k-k)!}{(k-k)!}}$$
So, $P(k)$ is true.

Suppose $P(a+1)$ holds for $k-1\ge a$. We need to prove $P(a)$ is true. Note that:
$$\begin{align}f(a) &= f(a+1) + \frac{2^aa(2k-a-1)!}{(k-a)!} \\
&= \color{red}{\frac{2^{a+1}(2k-a-1)!}{(k-a-1)!}} + \frac{2^aa(2k-a-1)!}{(k-a)!} \\
&= \frac{2^a(2k-a-1)!}{(k-a-1)!}\left(2+\frac{a}{k-a}\right) \\
&= \frac{2^a(2k-a-1)!}{(k-a-1)!}\cdot \frac{2k-a}{k-a} \\
&= \color{red}{\frac{2^a(2k-a)!}{(k-a)!}} \tag*{$\blacksquare$}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: $P(1)$ is equivalent to the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much!